# The import android.app.Activity is never used and app stopped unexpectedly

Tags: java, android, android-layout, admob, forceclose

**hey There finally I'm create android app and integer ad mob but when try it on my emulator get me stopped unexpectedly**
**here my code's file**

**cordova-2.2.0**
**admobskd 6.2.1**
**android 2.2**

**Here mainActivity.java**

```
    package com.afrogfx.VerbTenses;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import com.google.ads.*;

    import org.apache.cordova.*;

    public class VerbTenses extends DroidGap
    {
private static final String AdMob_Ad_Unit = "ass0bcc0e6a0228";
private AdView adView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/overview.html");

    //admob
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, AdMob_Ad_Unit); 
    super.root.addView(adView); 
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    //request.setTesting(false);
    adView.loadAd(request);
    }
    }
```

**Here manifest.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
  package="com.afrogfx.VerbTenses" 
  android:versionName="1.1" 
  android:versionCode="5" >

<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />



<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    >

    <activity android:name="VerbTenses" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>

</application>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="2" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
    </manifest>
```

**Warning**
The import android.app.Activity is never used

**console**
http://www.flickr.com/photos/afrogfx/8350084864/

**LogCat**
http://www.flickr.com/photos/afrogfx/8350087082/

```
    01-05 17:21:21.565: D/dalvikvm(726): DexOpt: couldn't find static field
    01-05 17:21:21.565: W/dalvikvm(726): VFY: unable to resolve static field 19 (SDK_INT) in Landroid/os/Build$VERSION;
    01-05 17:21:21.575: W/dalvikvm(726): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x60 at 0x0005
    01-05 17:21:21.575: W/dalvikvm(726): VFY:  rejected Lorg/apache/cordova/DroidGap;.init ()V
    01-05 17:21:21.575: W/dalvikvm(726): Verifier rejected class Lorg/apache/cordova/DroidGap;
    01-05 17:21:21.575: W/dalvikvm(726): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/afrogfx/VerbTenses/VerbTenses;)
    01-05 17:21:21.589: D/AndroidRuntime(726): Shutting down VM
    01-05 17:21:21.589: W/dalvikvm(726): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4000fe70)
    01-05 17:21:21.607: E/AndroidRuntime(726): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
    01-05 17:21:21.625: E/AndroidRuntime(726): java.lang.VerifyError: org.apache.cordova.DroidGap
    01-05 17:21:21.625: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    01-05 17:21:21.625: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1472)
    01-05 17:21:21.625: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1097)
    01-05 17:21:21.625: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2186)
    01-05 17:21:21.625: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
    01-05 17:21:21.625: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:112)
    01-05 17:21:21.625: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692)
    01-05 17:21:21.625: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    01-05 17:21:21.625: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    01-05 17:21:21.625: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
    01-05 17:21:21.625: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-05 17:21:21.625: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    01-05 17:21:21.625: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
    01-05 17:21:21.625: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
    01-05 17:21:21.625: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    01-05 17:21:21.644: I/dalvikvm(726): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
    01-05 17:21:21.745: I/dalvikvm(726): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    01-05 17:23:13.524: I/Process(726): Sending signal. PID: 726 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please add the logcat output to the question. It'll most likely contain essential information to diagnose your problem.

Comment: @Codo i do it 
**console** [link](http://www.flickr.com/photos/afrogfx/8350084864/)

**LogCat** [link](http://www.flickr.com/photos/afrogfx/8350087082/)

Comment: @Simon i found it and add links ;) please Help me console http://www.flickr.com/photos/afrogfx/8350084864/

LogCat http://www.flickr.com/photos/afrogfx/8350087082/

Comment: @Codo Thanks Bro :D Finally my application is  working but when i add  `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"`  ad banner show like this **you must have adactivity declared in androidmanifest.xml with configchanges**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a conflict with the Android version. I couldn't find the definitive reference but PhoneGap seems to require at least Android SDK version 7 (Android 2.1).

Set the following in your `manifest.xml`:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
```

You might also need to create a new emulator instance with a higher Android version.